# Como buscar por medio de ID y modificar o eliminar ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

les comento que este es mi codigo  de Actualizar, de este código les dejo mi controlador que hice, la pregunta es como puedo hacer mi método de para que busque por id y posteriormente haga la acción de eliminar o actualizar, serian tan amables de apoyarme, por favor, dejo mi metodo de liminar..

```
 public  void Actualizar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string actualizar = "update Persona set nombre='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "',Apellido='" + objAlumno.Apellido1 + "',Telefono='" + objAlumno.Telefono1 + "' Where idAlumno ='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCommand(actualizar, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
        }
```

---

```
     public ActionResult Editar()
                {
                    return View();
                }
                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Editar(Alumno objAlumno)
                {



                AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
    ins.find(objAlumno);
    //AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
    //ins.Actualizar(objAlumno);
    return View("Editar" );

                }
______________________________________________________________________________

   public void Eliminar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string eliminar = "'delete from Persona where idAlumno ='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCommand(eliminar, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
        }
```

---

Este es mi metodo buscar

```
public bool find(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            bool ExistenRegistros;
            string find = "select * from Persona where idAlumno = '" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCommand(find, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                SqlDataReader read = conn.ExecuteReader();
                ExistenRegistros = read.Read();
                if (ExistenRegistros)
                {
                    objAlumno.IdAlumno = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                    objAlumno.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Apellido1 = read[2].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Telefono1 = read[3].ToString();

                    objAlumno.Estado = 99;

                }
                else
                {
                    objAlumno.Estado = 1;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
            return ExistenRegistros;

        }
```

Comment: Qué es precisamente lo que te falla?

Comment: ya hice algo así pero no busca y no llena los campos para que los edite y los aguarde de nuevo 

 public ActionResult Editar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            Alumno buscar = new Alumno();
            buscar.idAlumno.ToString();
            //AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
            //ins.Actualizar(objAlumno);
            return View("Editar");
            
        }

Comment: El **IdAlumno** es numérico? porque en ese caso las comillas dobles no aplican, sólo deberías buscarlo de esta forma `select * from Persona where idAlumno = ' + objAlumno.IdAlumno + '`

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera gracias por tu aporte ya lo he resuelto :D lo de buscar por otro lado no me llena los campos de de nombre apellido, telefono cuando lo busco hice algo como esto.
 public ActionResult Editar(string id)
        { 
            AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
            Alumno busca = new Alumno();
            busca = ins.find(id);
            return View(busca);
        }

Comment: Era el ID? o era otra cosa la que no funcionaba?

Comment: no buscaba el por el id, ya busca pero no llena los datos en los campos :/ que menciono en tu comentario anterior :/